# Lorentz Transformation Explanation

Tags: special-relativity

Could anyone explain what Lorentz transformation actually does? Is it only used to convert coordinates of one reference frame to the same kind of coordinates of another reference frame?

Comment: This is vague and doesn't show much research effort. The Lorentz transformation can also be used to transform vectors such as energy-momentum vectors.

Comment: A better way to ask is  to cite an explanation in a textbook or on the web,and then say which part of the explanation you don't follow and why.

Comment: If you are asking what it is "ALL" about,  then it is to be noted that if a proper and complete explanation is given, it can be and will be suffice enough for you to then proceed to derive all of the Lorentz Transformation equations from such a complete explanation. If the explanation is fragmented in any way, then of course you will not be able to derive the equations via the starting with a fragmented description of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does rotations of the coordinate frame in spacetime. If you refer to the inhomogeneous Lorentz group it's often called the Poincare group which includes also translations.

The Lorentz transformation was originally the transformation of coordinates where one frame is moving at a constant velocity wrt another. Because it is relativistic it mixes space and time, so it is used to, in its simplest form, obtain space contraction and time dilation in special relativity. Those transformations are called boosts, they boost one inertial reference frame wrt to another. And they do that while insuring that the velocity of light is the same in all such frames.

But it turns out that to make it a group you have to include also spatial rotations, and then to complete it all to include all possible inertial frame transformation in special relativity you include the translations. As @Ben Crowell notes in his comment then it allows you to transform scalars, vectors, Tensors etc from one inertial reference frame in special relativity to another. So those are the group of transformations that preserve the speed of light. That accommodates perfectly special relativity.